# Using the ID column create a customised ID column

Tags: custom-list

I want to concatecate two columns.... one being the ID column.
When I add a calculated column I do not see the ID column in the list of columns I can use?

Comment: Yes, using a Workflow is one option. But depending on what you want to do with the ID there might be others. Can you explain what and why you want to use ID?

Comment: I want a unique item number of each item on the list
NMS0001
NMS0002

Comment: Then use the SP Designer Workflow method. [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28986458/columns-dereferencing-in-sharepoints-calculated-column) does not apply to your usecase (but might be interesting to know)

Answer (score 0):

The ID column is not usable in calculated columns.

If you want to use it, you can in workflow. My experience with that has been mixed, sometimes it does not work as expected. You might be able to mitigate that by pausing for one minute as the first action in the workflow.

Answer (score 0):

The ID is generated once a new list item is created. So it cannot be used in calculated columns. So as described by Eric, create a new column called ID and set its value using a workflow.